# "Order by Col1, Col2" using entity framework

Tags: c#, .net, linq, entity-framework

I need to order by 2 columns using the entity framework.

How is that done?

```
return _repository.GetSomething().OrderBy(x => x.Col1   .. Col2)?
```

i.e

```
SELECT * FROM Foo ORDER BY Col1, Col2
```

Answer (score 337, accepted):

Try `OrderBy(x => x.Col1).ThenBy(x => x.Col2)`. It is a LINQ feature, anyway, not exclusive to EF.

Answer (score 65):

Another way:

```
qqq.OrderBy(x => new { x.Col1, x.Col2} )
```

Comment: How do you order descending this way?

Comment: qqq.OrderByDescending(x => new { x.Col1, x.Col2} )

Comment: I get an "At least one object must implement IComparable" error message when used with EntityFramework Core on two string fields.

Comment: Note, I came here looking for EF Core, so this error is probably exclusive to that but: _"Invalid anonymous type member declarator. Anonymous type members must be declared with a member assignment, simple name or member access. [uk.ac.sahfos.cpr.console.web]csharp(CS0746)"_

Answer (score 43):

Try:

```
OrderBy(x => x.Col1).ThenBy(x => x.Col2)
```

For order by descending try this:

```
OrderByDescending (x => x.Col1).ThenByDescending (x => x.Col2)
```

Answer (score 6):

Following sorting happens in the DB level. Not on the returned result.

Try:

```
IQueryable<a>.OrderBy("col1 asc, col2 asc")
```

Example 1:

```
ctx.CateringOrders.OrderBy("Details.DeliveryDate asc, Details.DeliveryTime asc")
```

Example 2:

```
ctx.CateringOrders.OrderBy("{0} {1}, {2} {3}", 
    "Details.DeliveryDate", "asc",
    "Details.DeliveryTime", "asc" 
)
```

Where 
`IQueryable<a>` is entity query,
`"col1 asc"` is column 1 and sorting direction
`"col2 asc"` is column 2 and sorting direction

Comment: You need to use System.Linq.Dynamic.Core to do this

Answer (score -7):

Please note, this will not work with Telerik's Grid or any other Telerik's DataSource component. Although it uses prefiltered IQueryable object, sorting is always done automatically as last step effectively overriding your sorting settings.

You have to follow: [Specifying default sort in grid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23393506/specifying-default-sort-in-grid)