# Specifying default sort in grid

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, kendo-grid, knockout-kendo

Is it possible to specify a default sort when using the knockout-kendo binding to bind the Telerik Kendo grid?

I am binding the grid like this:

```
kendoGrid: { data: grid.Rows, sortable: {allowUnsort: false,mode:'single'}, columns: grid.Columns}
```

However, I have not found a way to specify the default sort. 
Standard Kendo has a `sort:{field:"Col1",dir:"asc"}` element that can be specified on the data source, but it's unclear how this can be applied to the `kendoGrid` binding

Default Kendo sort element: http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/framework/datasource#sort-array--objectdefault

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The comments from the following answer gave me a clue:

[What is the difference between the data and dataSource in knockout-kendo grid widget?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22688217/what-is-the-difference-between-the-data-and-datasource-in-knockout-kendo-grid-wi)

It seems like you can use data and dataSource in tandem if you want to specify this behavior:

```
kendoGrid: {dataSource:{sort:{field:'Col1',dir:'asc'}}, data: grid.Rows, sortable: {allowUnsort: false,mode:'single'}, columns: grid.Columns}
```

Answer (score 2):

Check out the following post in the kendo forums.

http://www.telerik.com/forums/default-sort-for-kendo-grid-mvc

```
.DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
        .Ajax()
        .Sort(sort => sort.Add("City").Ascending()) // <-- initial sort expression
        .Read(read => read.Action("Index", "Home"))
    )
```

Comment: This question is about using a Kendo Grid with JavaScript, not MVC, so this answer should be improved by providing details and examples in JavaScript.